# Sorting a dictionary by a given list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Is there a simple way to sort a dictionary by a given list?

Example:

```
data = OrderedDict([('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2'), ('pu', 'var3')])
order = ['pu', 'pi', 'pa']
```

requested ordered dictionary:

```
>>> OrderedDict([('pu', 'var3'), ('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2')])
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the following generator comprehension:

```
sorted_data = OrderedDict((k, data[k]) for k in order)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a lambda function (`lambda t: order.index(t[0])`) for the `key` parameter in `OrderedDict` is one way to do it:

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [2]: order = ['pu', 'pi', 'pa']
In [3]: data = OrderedDict([('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2'), ('pu', 'var3')])
In [4]: OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: order.index(t[0])))
Out[4]: OrderedDict([('pu', 'var3'), ('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2')])
```

Documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> counter = itertools.count()
>>> input = [('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2'), ('pu', 'var3')]
>>> order = {key: counter.next() for key in ['pu', 'pi', 'pa']}

>>> OrderedDict(sorted(input, key=lambda pair: order[pair[0]]))
OrderedDict([('pu', 'var3'), ('pi', 'var1'), ('pa', 'var2')])
```